# Error when I try to fetch image from postgresql 9.6.13 database, after disable "standard_conforming_strings = off", but insert images are finely good

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have stored an image in database as `"bytea"`(data type) in `postgresql 9.6.13` and before I have changed `"standard_conforming_strings = off"`  in **VERSION/PLATFORM COMPATIBILITY**. But I have get and set image `"byte[]"` in `java code (Version jdk1.8)`.
Insertion process are finely good. But I can't able to fetch image from the database.

In ImageScanDTO.java

private byte[] image;

```
public byte[] getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] scanImage) {
    this.image = scanImage;
}
```

In ImageScanDAO.java

```
imageScanDTO.setImage(rs.getBytes("scan_image"));
```

Image store like in database :

> \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

Comment: What happens when you try to get it from the database? With what kind of code? It’s impossible to say anything without knowing what exactly you’re trying to do and what happens when you do it. Errors? What errors?

Comment: Did you write java code to fetch an image from your _PostgreSQL_ database? If yes, please [edit] your question and add that code.

Comment: Your title says you get an error, but no exception stacktrace is present in your question. Please post a [mre] with all relevant error information.